# Weekly raster data for temperature and precipitation in US

Tags: raster, data, spatio-temporal-data

I am looking for weekly raster data for US for temperature and precipitation. All the major datasets PRISM, WorldClim etc. are either on a monthly scale or daily scale. I was wondering if anyone has aggregated data for weekly values from daily data or can point me to links where I can get it. I am looking for data for years 2005-2011. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this on the [**Open Data beta Stack Exchange**](http://opendata.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for pointing me to that. I will shift it over.